# Webpack, Babel, MobX and compiler assumptions

Tags: webpack, babeljs, mobx, babel-loader

I have a large codebase that used mobx and mobx-react-lite. I recently used react scripts but now want to switch to vanilla webpack config.

In the webpack config, I added this:

```js
{
  test: /\.(jsx?|tsx?)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: "babel-loader",
},
```

Then I added following babel config:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env"],
    ["@babel/preset-react", { "runtime": "automatic" }],
    ["@babel/preset-typescript"]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

and it works fine.

But in the documentation for these plugins, I read the following:

> Consider migrating to the top level setPublicClassFields assumption

> Consider migrating to the top level privateFieldsAsProperties assumption.

So, I tried to migrate:

```json
{
  "assumptions": {
    "privateFieldsAsProperties": false,
    "setPublicClassFields": false
  },
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env"],
    ["@babel/preset-react", { "runtime": "automatic" }],
    ["@babel/preset-typescript"]
  ]
}
```

and now `observer` from `mobx-react-lite` package not working. No errors in console.

What I missing?